# Making a bordered box in C with a movable character

Tags: c

I am having a couple issues, I am learning C throug the [Zed Shaw Book](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/), and I thought I would take a small break and try and put what I have learned so far to the test. But then I got stuck.

The first issue is **Creating an empty box.** I cannot seem to do this. I Can Create a box, missing the bottom part but it is filled in by '*', if I just do `''` then the c compiler states: `create_border.c:12:14: error: expected expression`

The second issue, is I dont know how to connect to the keyboard so that when I press Up, Down, Left, Right a character, `@` in this case, moves around and stops when it his an edge.

All I have so far is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_Y 6
#define MAX_X 6

void print_board(char board[MAX_Y][MAX_X]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char exampleBoard[MAX_Y][MAX_X] = {
        {'x','-','-','-','-','x'},
        {'|','*','*','*','*','|'},
        {'|','*','*','*','*','|'},
        {'|','*','*','*','*','|'},
        {'|','*','*','*','*','|'},
        {'x','-','-','-','-','x'}
    };

    print_board(exampleBoard);

    return 0;
}

void print_board(char board[MAX_Y][MAX_X]) {

    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;

    for(row = 0; row < MAX_Y; row++) {
        for(col = 0; col < MAX_X; col++) {
            printf("%c", board[row][col]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n\n");
}
```

All this prints out is:

```
x----x
|****|
|****|
|****|
|****|
```

So heres what I expect:

- **An empty box, with no `'*'` and a `@` character any where in the box.**
- **Ability to move `@` and have it stop when it reaches a border.**

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You could replace `''` by `' '` (A space character). And, can you tell which OS are you using? Because arrow key codes are different for different OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a terminal, an "empty case" is a space character. You can write it with `' '`  instead of `''`.

Then, for reading keyboard, you can make it with [read](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) syscall directly from your terminal. But the default configuration of your terminal will force you to press `enter` between each key to make your read works.

NOTE: You could make this kind of ASCII-programming simplier using a library like [ncurses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/intro.html).